# facebook mobile_iframe callback doesnt work

Tags: javascript, facebook, share

I have some strange problem with facebook share button options. When I use mobile_iframe option, to open a popup diaglog, not a new window, response callback doesn't work. So I can not understand do user click Share button, or not.
Here is the code example:

```
if(type == 'facebook') {
    FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    mobile_iframe: true,
    title: '',
    quote: '',
    hashtag: '#',
    picture: '',
    href: ''        
   }, function(response){
        if(response && !response.error_code) {

        }
   };
```

Comment: What do you need the callback for?

Comment: you've got a syntax error. there is no closing bracket for the ui method

Comment: I need to know that use share my content on Facebook. In desktop version its works fine, but with mobile frame no any response. So if user just close the dialog, its the same as he tap share button